# ASP.Net Core - Customer Formatter takes precedence

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I followed the example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and written my customer formatter below. It works fine, however the issue is it always runs first and doesn't take into account it should only run when Accept Header is text/csv.

```
public class CSVFormatter : TextOutputFormatter
{
    private string FileName { get; set; }

    public CSVFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/csv"));

        SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.UTF8);
        SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.Unicode);
    }

    protected override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        return IsTypeOfIEnumerable(type);
    }

    private bool IsTypeOfIEnumerable(Type type)
    {
        foreach (Type interfaceType in type.GetInterfaces())
        {
            if (interfaceType == typeof(IEnumerable))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public override Task WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
    {
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider = context.HttpContext.RequestServices;

        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        var buffer = new StringBuilder();
        var value = context.Object;
        var type = context.ObjectType;

        WriteData(type, value, buffer, response);

        return response.WriteAsync(buffer.ToString());
    }

    private void WriteData(Type type, object value, StringBuilder buffer, HttpResponse response)
    {
        //NOTE: We have check the type inside CanWriteType method. If request comes this far, the type is IEnumerable. We are safe.

        Type itemType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];

        //Write out columns
        buffer.AppendLine(string.Join<string>(",", itemType.GetProperties().Select(x => x.Name.ToLower())));

        foreach (var obj in (IEnumerable<object>)value)
        {
            var vals = obj.GetType().GetProperties().Select(pi => new { Value = pi.GetValue(obj, null) });
            string valueLine = string.Empty;

            foreach (var val in vals)
            {
                var columnValue = val.Value;
                valueLine = string.Concat(valueLine, columnValue, ",");
            }

            valueLine = valueLine.Substring(0, valueLine.Length - 1);

            buffer.AppendLine(valueLine);
        }
    }
}
```

I added it to Starup.cs like this:

```
 services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
                options.OutputFormatters.Insert(0, new CSVFormatter());
            })
```

Pre Asp.net core, in .Net I only ran my Custom Formatter when I needed it by specifying a certain query string "**format=csv**" for.e.g.

So couple of questions:

- How can I force it to only run when I want.
- Also can I pass a file name in Query string or header and read it in the custom formatter and add it like this.

*`headers.Add("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", FileName));`*

Comment: Your code looks good. Are you sure you are not sending the `Accept` header with `text/csv` in your requests?

Comment: @JuanR I am simply hitting Run from Visual Studio or using browser or RestAPI Client (similar to Postman) to test it. I doubt both of these steps will automatically send that header.

Comment: Not that it would make a difference, but at this point, anything is worth trying. Replace `MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/csv")` for  `new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/csv")`.

Comment: @JuanR , just tried replacing but it doesn't help.

Comment: I think I may know what your problem is. Because you are inserting the new formatter at index `0`, you are essentially configuring it to be the default. Try adding it to the collection instead: `options.OutputFormatters.Add(new CSVFormatter());`.